# iOS6 putting a different subview into an existing subview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have a xib file with a segmented control and a target view.  I have added three other subviews to this zib file.  I want to put the appropriate subview into target view when user selects the segmented control.  I cannot get my appropriate subview to display.  Here is my code:

```
// putting all 3 views in the target frame
self.activationView.frame = self.targetView.frame;
self.preferencesView.frame = self.targetView.frame;
self.aboutView.frame = self.targetView.frame;

// show the appropriate frame
self.targetView.hidden = YES;
self.preferencesView.hidden = YES;
self.aboutView.hidden = YES;

self.activationView.hidden = NO;
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
 [UIView transitionFromView:SourceView 
                            toView:DestinationView
                          duration:0.5 
                           options:(UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight)
                        completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                            if (finished) 
                            {
                                NSLog(@"Changed View");
                            }
                        }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the 3 views aren't subviews of targetView? if so, then if you hide targetView you wont be able to see the subviews either.